# Gradle dependencies pom files locations on local file system

Tags: gradle

I understand that Gradle stores project dependencies cache in `~/.gradle/caches/modules-2` for the actual `jar` files. However, does Gradle also store `.pom` anywhere locally? Also, if I previously downloaded same dependencies through Maven (stored in `~/.m2/repositories`) would Gradle reuse them automatically? In Maven, pomfiles are downloaded along side jars.

If POMs are not downloaded as part of gradle build, what's the best way to programmatically get the POMs for package metadata?

Comment: Gradle is not Maven; the POM is likely only read from remote repositories - or `mavenLocal()`.

Answer (score 0):

Gradle seems to use a local cache and not a repository, unless depending on `mavenLoacal()`.
You could use the API which `mavenCentral()` provides:
https://central.sonatype.org/search/rest-api-guide

Comment: this would work but can be slow and costly if I have a lot of dependencies

Comment: This wasn't the question - and when downloading to `mavenLocal()` ...Gradle can use that, too. It resolves the dependencies in the order in which the repositories are being declared in `settings.gradle`. https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/core_dependency_management.html#sec:dependency-mgmt-in-gradle

Comment: majority of gradle dependencies would be pulled from `mavenCentral()` or `google()`. In such cases, the local cache wouldn't contain POMs

Comment: A cache is not a repository... there simply is no POM unless you'd download POM.